# Converting a string of LEDs that were powered by 3 AA batteries to a switching power supply

Tags: led

[image]In addition to the switching power supply, I connected a buck boost converter.  The batteries provided 4.5 V to the LEDs.  However, the switching power supply would deliver 5 V with 3A. I adjusted the buck boost converter to deliver 4.5 V. I reused the original resister but when I turn on the lights, the resister quite quickly heats up to a point that I need to shut it off. I would believe the resister needs to be replaced with one that can resist the increased current.  What resister do I need to use so that it won't overheat and of course protect the LEDs.

Comment: This is more electrical design than Home Improvement.

Comment: Batteries have quite a bit of internal resistance that the power supply doesn't have. This effectively means that the resistor has to dissipate more power because the LEDs are running at a higher current. Try turning the power supply down to 4.2 V and see if that helps. Can you post an image of the resistor that you currently use along with a ruler of some sort so the physical size can be determined (size can indicate wattage rating).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on [electronics.se].

Comment: It’s ohms law p=I x E . Measure the voltage drop or current in both cases you will find the power dissipation of a 1/4 watt resistor is not enough because of the difference in voltage from a power supply compared to a battery. Increasing the resistance will reduce the current. If you are happy with the voltages double the resistance and put 2 in parallel that would provide the same resistance and double the wattage. But I agree this should go to another SE forum.

Comment: I'd consider using a buck converter module that has an in-built current limit and using that setting to set the led brightness, then the resistor is not needed. Search "DC-DC CV CC"

Comment: If the voltage is the same then the resistor should be fine. Are you sure you wired it up correctly? Are you sure your buck converter is set at the right voltage? Are you sure your power supply is outputting a good regulated 5V?

Comment: Personally I replace the converter with a simple 1n400x diode. It provides 0.7V drop perfect for this.

Comment: Just dial down the output voltage of your buck until the resistor no longer over-heats.

Comment: @dandavis  for your comment.  Lowered the converter output to 3.5 V.  At 4V the resistor temp very slowly increased.  Lowered to 3.5 V and temp dropped and was stable at 90 degrees F.  Finger touch the resister felt cool.  LEDs were a little dimmer but acceptable and your comment is acceptable.